# Effect of the birthday bound on AES-GCM

Tags: aes, gcm, birthday-attack

What is the effect of the birthday bound on the security of AES-GCM, when a very large number of messages are encrypted?

I am looking for attacks that are useful in obtaining information about the plaintext and/or creating forgeries, not just distinguishers.

Comment: related: [Security of encrypting many short values with AES in GCM mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/32105/23623)